# Change permalink for custom post in Wordpress 3.5

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting, permalinks

Please forgive me if this problem has been solved, but I searched and none of the solutions presented here seemed to match my situation.

I had a plugin programmed to create a custom post type called "Exercises". When I first create the post, the plugin assigns the title to the post URL. For example:

```
mysite dot com/?exercise=pushups
```

The permalink setting are the default `mysite dot com/?p=123`, but the plugin somehow assigns the custom post title to the URL so it appears as shown above.

With a regular post, I'm able to change the post title and the permalink is changed. However, the problem I'm having is I'm unable to edit the URL title with the custom post after initial creation. For example, I was hoping for this:

```
mysite dot com/?exercise/%postname%/
```

Where I can edit `postname` directly from the post admin page.

Does anyone know what could be causing this and where I could make the changes? The programmers suggested that it would require nginx rewrite configuration (which they are not familiar with. Is there any way to change this so I can edit title after I've created the exercise? I tried changing the permalink settings but that made the custom plugin not functional.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: post also your wp_register_post_type function...

Comment: I think the use of `/%postname%/` in you permalinks settings is implied in the "Exercises" plugin, not the default setting `?p=123`. Maybe you should check the plugin's documentation for the answer to your question.